# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am converting an ASP.NET MVC application to ASP.NET MVC 2, and I get the following error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider'

Here is the code:

```
public static void AddRuleViolation(this ModelStateDictionary modelState,
                                    RuleViolation error, 
                                    FormCollection collection)
{
    modelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
    modelState.SetModelValue(error.PropertyName, 
                             collection.ToValueProvider()[error.PropertyName]);
}
```

How can this be remedied?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation changed between ASP.NET MVC 1 and 2 for `IValueProvider`.

Try using the `GetValue()` method instead of referencing it by index.

```
collection.ToValueProvider().GetValue(error.PropertyName)
```

Comment: I ran into this in a slightly different context in some old code: `ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["controller"]` throws an error, but `ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller")` works.